# EC2 Instance Crashes and need to restart from terminal

Tags: amazon-ec2, terminal, ec2-api-tools

I have an amazon ec2 instance that I usually ssh into using terminal. I was making some changes and my terminal froze. So, I closed terminal and tried to ssh again. But, I am getting no response.

I *think* that the instance has crashed and I need to restart, but I have no idea how to do this. Problem is: I don't have access to the instance online because the username and password belongs to someone else on my team (who I currently can't contact, out of country).

How can I restart the server from terminal? I tried downloading the Amazon EC2 API Tools, but without setup instructions, I'm lost (I tried these: http://linuxsysadminblog.com/2009/06/howto-get-started-with-amazon-ec2-api-tools/ but got stuck on private key. I only have one pem file?)

Thanks.

Comment: It is likely that you won't be able to connect if you don't have both of the files, the private key AND the X.509 certificate. It is likely that, unfortunately, you will need to ask for a reboot from the EC2 console, or for a X.509 certificate (generated from the EC2 console).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the Cert and the key, there is no way to do it. I would ask them for access to the EC2 Management Console. If they setup IAM, you can have limited access to just the tools you need.